# Add entities relation to a 3rd table in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I need help about Entity Framework. I have a diagram like this :

[image: Diagram Entity Framework]

Description:

when I execute code to insert into database from `Fly_Product` entity

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(ProductVM obj)
{
        try
        {
            obj.Product.Published = obj.isPublish;
            obj.Product.Deleted = obj.isDelete;
            obj.Product.ShowOnHomePage = obj.isHome;

            obj.ProductVariant.IsShipEnabled = obj.isShipEnabled;
            obj.ProductVariant.IsFreeShipping = obj.isFreeShipping;
            obj.ProductVariant.CallForPrice = obj.isCallForPrice;
            obj.ProductVariant.isHot = obj.isHot;
            obj.ProductVariant.isNew = obj.isNew;
            obj.ProductVariant.isGift = obj.isGift;
            obj.ProductVariant.Fly_ProductVariant_Discount_Mapping.Add(new Fly_ProductVariant_Discount_Mapping { DiscountID = obj.indexDiscount, Createdon = DateTime.Now });
            obj.Product.Fly_ProductVariant.Add(obj.ProductVariant);

            obj.Product.Fly_ProductLocalized.Add(obj.ProductLocalized);
            obj.Product.Fly_ProductPicture.Add(obj.ProductPictures);

            obj.Product.Fly_Product_Category_Mapping.Add(new Fly_Product_Category_Mapping { CategoryID = obj.indexCate });
            obj.Product.Fly_Product_Manufacturer_Mapping.Add(new Fly_Product_Manufacturer_Mapping { ManufacturerID = obj.indexManufacturer });

            repository.Add(obj.Product);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View(e.Message);
        }
}
```

DataAccess:

```
public void Add(Fly_Product obj)
{
        try
        {
            using (var context = new flycameraEntities())
            {
                context.Fly_Product.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

and catch exception:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Fly_ProductVariant_Discount_Mapping'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Fly_ProductVariant_Discount_Mapping'

**Solved** :
i forget assign column `DiscountMappingID` auto-incremented. thanks **Gert Arnold** was helped

Comment: show the code that is being used to perform the insert; without it, we have no idea what you are doing wrong.  Also, this can't be the entire diagram;  There are more Navigation properties on that `Fly_ProductVariant` table than you are showing.  are you sure that you have your model structured correctly?

Comment: hi claies, i was edited code above, image entity above i capture it from Model Browser of visual studio

Comment: Is  `DiscountMappingID` an identity column (auto-incremented)?

Comment: yup!, it auto-incremented.